# Python - Get current UTC time. Ignore computer clock always

Tags: python, datetime, utc, clock

Does anyone have any tips to get the current UTC time, from online somewhere, and write some decent python code assuming my computer clock is always wrong?

```
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow() #---> assume always wrong
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()    #---> assume always wrong
```

Using '.utcnow()' or '.now()' both depend upon the accuracy of my computer clock.
I want to write the code assuming that if it runs from a computer with a bad clock, it still gets the correct time.

BACKGROUND:

I am trying to retool my code to entirely live in UTC time.
My use case is to do some time series analysis.
I keep finding myself accidentally being off 5 hours from EST, or off 1 hour from daylight savings when doing calculations.
The tools within the datetime.datetime objects are great, however it would be nice be able to flag some setting when importing the datetime library and prevent reading my computer clock entirely, to avoid any accidental clock badness issue.

EXAMPLE OF CODE I AM LOOKING FOR:

```
import datetime
import requests

#force datetime libaries to never read my computer clock:
datetime.some_settings_function( readcomputerclock = False/'Never' )

#get the current time with some API:
current_utc_date_and_time_from_online = requests.get(...) #some api get request
current_utc_datetime = transform( current_utc_date_and_time_from_oneline )

#Transform back and forth to UTC Epoch time:
current_utc_epoch = current_utc_datetime.timestamp()
current_utc_datetime_again = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_utc_epoch)
#current_utc_datetime == current_utc_datetime_again

#Trigger exception with new settings, when i accidentally write code 
#    that would ask datetime library to attempt to read computer clock:
fail_code_line = datetime.datetime.now()
# >>> trigger some exception here
```

TLDR; I am looking for a reliable UTC api for python, and a way to prevent datetime from ever reading my computer clock again.

UPDATE: After accepting the provided answer it has become clear to me for my purposes, trusting my computer clock for a few seconds after updating my computer clock from a trusted source, then asking my computer clock for UTC time within those few seconds is good enough. It is a feasible coding practice to write a "get UTC time now" code using all the information within the accepted answer, that is accurate to within a second or two. (No I have not done the statistical confidence interval posterior on the accuracy) It is then further feasible to write all the rest of my code such that all logic will assume UTC time.

Comment: Using an NTP library with some NTP server of your choice would probably be the sanest approach.

Comment: How about https://pypi.org/project/ntplib/?

Comment: Remember that your computer's clock is perfectly fine for short intervals.  A crystal is typically accurate to better than 100 parts per million, which is 8 seconds per day, and most are much better than that.  The key is to run an NTP client that synchronizes to a good NTP server on a regular basis.  You can get a GPS-based NTP server for your network for $300 (https://timemachinescorp.com/product/gps-time-server-tm1000a/).

Comment: I am not worried about accuracy within a few seconds. I am worried about my future self being an idiot. I want to write my code so I can run it in NYC this week, California next week, and Italy the week after, and the whole time I have no idea when daylight savings time starts or ends.  My times should all be within a few seconds long as I load in UTC times directly from a data source properly.

Comment: But then you don't need any server. Just use `datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)`

Comment: Yeah, a clock is only *wrong* if it doesn’t have the correct time of anywhere. If its clock is *correct* and just not set to your current timezone, then it’s still *correct*. Don’t overcomplicate your code for the wrong reasons.

Comment: See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html

Comment: That blogpost is great and gets to the core of my issues. I keep struggling to understand which function calls are making use of my computer clock, and which are not.

Comment: @DAdams Would you mind editing the question title or adding "UPDATE: " line at the bottom?  The question title contradicts the accepted answer.  (You do end up trusting the local clock for a window of time after the NTP diff/sync.)

Comment: @yzorg I attempted to update the question to better address the discrepancy between question and answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Getting correct, timezone aware datetimes and unix timestamps

Turns out this question was rather about how to convert to / from unix timestamps and datetimes.

The correct solution in python 3 should be:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# get the current utc time
t = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

# convert to unix, this will keep the utc timezone
unix = t.timestamp()

# convert back to datetime, specifying that the timestamp is in UTC
t2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix, tz=timezone.utc)
```

#### Other timezones

Since python 3.9, the stdlib has the zoneinfo library, you can use this to convert between timezones.
For python < 3.9, you have to use a thirdparty library like `dateutil`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

now_berlin = datetime.now(ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin'))
now_ny = now_berlin.astimezone(ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))

print('Time in Berlin:', now_berlin)
print('Time in New York', now_ny)
```

### Actually using ntp instead of the computer clock

You can use `ntplib`:

```
from ntplib import NTPClient
from datetime import datetime, timezone

client = NTPClient()
response = client.request('europe.pool.ntp.org', version=3)

time = datetime.fromtimestamp(resp.tx_time, tz=timezone.utc)
```

Edit: I however don't see a real reason, why just from traveling this should go wrong:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

for more information see: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html

Comment: Seeing the api solution side by side with the local solution is very helpful.

Comment: But the local clock will change from something like 12:00 Europe/Berlin to 8:00 America/New_York, which is the same time.

There should be no reason that the utc time should change in any meaningful way other than getting better because you actually synced with an NTP server again.

Comment: I suppose my hesitation comes from ignorance. I assume that datetime.now() will read the timezone and time in properly from the linux box. How I do I have faith, that my computer's timezone and time are correct?

Comment: Your timezone should only change when *you* change it. I don't know of any linux distribution that sets the timezone automatically via ntp / network. And even then: explicitly asking for UTC / a fixed timezone should always work since your computer won't adjust the time without also storing the current timezone. Linux even stores UTC in the hardware clock (as opposed to windows that stores local time, which leads to problems in dual boot systems you can fix by setting a windows registry key so that windows also stores/assumes UTC)

Comment: Can you help me get the last 5% over the finish line here: If I go to and from epoch timestamp with your 'dt=datetime.now(timezone.utc)' will that avoid looking at my computer clock? Am I supposed to use  ".timestamp()"  and ".fromtimestamp()" to get epochs in UTC?

Comment: All this will use you computer clock. (Aside from the ntlib stuff). But it will correctly convert to the timezone you ask (e.g. UTC). So if you want to have the current unix timestamp in UTC, do `datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp()`. To go from a UTC unix timestamp to a timezone aware datetime instance, do `datetime.fromtimestamp(unix, tz=timezone.utc)`

Comment: Perfect - this is what I was looking for.  
I kept finding myself going to unix timestamps inconsistently. Thank you so much for the help.